# Generate minutely time range in python

Tags: python, pandas, time

Currently I am generating hourly time using the below code

```
import pandas as pd
times=[pd.to_datetime(i) for i in '09:14:00','10:15:00','11:15:00','12:15:00','13:15:00','14:15:00','15:15:00', '15:30:00']
```

I need to have minutely times like `'09:14:00','09:15:00'`

Is there a way to have minutely times without hard coding `hh:mm:ss` like above.
I tried `pd.date_range("09:14:00", "15:31:00", freq="1min").time`
But the output is in a different type than what I expect

```
In [100]: pd.date_range("09:14:00", "09:15:00", freq="1min").time
Out[100]: array([datetime.time(9, 14), datetime.time(9, 15)], dtype=object)
#expected type
In [99]: pd.to_datetime("09:14:00")
Out[99]: Timestamp('2019-02-20 09:14:00')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think close what you need are `timedelta`s, because `Timestamp` with no date, only with time, not exist:

```
r1 = pd.timedelta_range("09:14:00", "09:20:00", freq="1min")
print (r1)
TimedeltaIndex(['09:14:00', '09:15:00', '09:16:00', '09:17:00', '09:18:00',
                '09:19:00', '09:20:00'],
               dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq='T')
```

Only is possible generate `time`s in `strings`:

```
r2 = pd.date_range("09:14:00", "09:20:00", freq="1min").strftime('%H:%M:%S').tolist()
print (r2)
['09:14:00', '09:15:00', '09:16:00', '09:17:00', '09:18:00', '09:19:00', '09:20:00']
```